# iMacros Set !DATASOURCE Error for Mac Chrome Extension

Tags: set, runtime, datasource, imacros

I received a RuntimeError: !DATASOURCE requires File IO interface, line: 5

I am using iMacros for Mac OS chrome extension. The code is from the Demo-Loop-Csv-2-Web

I have updated the demo code from:

```
SET !DATASOURCE Address.csv
```

to

```
SET !DATASOURCE Users/Me/Documents/iMacros/DataSources/address.csv
```

I added the file in the folder.

```
VERSION BUILD=11.5.497.9113
TAB T=1
TAB CLOSEALLOTHERS 
' Specify input file (if !COL variables are used, iMacros automatically assumes a CSV format of the input file
SET !DATASOURCE Users/me/Documents/iMacros/DataSources/address.csv
'Use the Play(Loop) button to run the macro in a loop
SET !LOOP 2
'Start at line 2 to skip the header in the file
'Increase the current position in the file with each loop 
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would be useful when you ask a Qt/open a Thread about iMacros if you could mention your FCI...
=> Probable FCI:

```
iMacros for CR v10.0.5 'Free', CR77, MacOS.
```

Then yep, Answer/Explanation is documented in the Wiki for 'iMacros for CR' + 'WebExtensions':
https://wiki.imacros.net/Webextensions#Add_File_Access

> iMacros File Access is only available for Windows. Currently we do not offer a version for Mac or Linux.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That makes sense. Thanks again for all your help.

Comment: Al_-_right...!, Thanks for accepting my Answer @OP, and OK, you understood that '!DATASOURCE' needs the FIO-Module (for Local File Access), same for 'SAVEAS TYPE EXTRACT' and 'ONDOWNLOAD + FOLDER'..., which unfortunately is only available (until now) for Win32/64... - If you still mention your FCI in this current Qt, + in your previous one, I might have a look at your previous one and answer it... (Just an Idea...) [I don't answer Qt's/Threads when FCI is not mentioned...] - [And I don't give '+1' to Qt's when FCI is not mentioned...]